# Work in an isothermal process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

Is it possible to calculate the work done on a gas by an isothermal process given pressure and volume? ie Pressure at point 2 is 5.55atm and volume is 1.39m^3. Temperature or number of moles is not given.

(a=1.39m^3 and b=1.85)

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, for an isothermal process $\Delta {T}=0$,

From the ideal gas equation, $PV=nRT$, you can get the value of $P$ and you can substitute the value in the expression of work. Isothermal processes are slow and reversible. So, the external pressure will be equal to the internal pressure.

$W=\int P_{ext} dV$

$ = \int_{V_1}^{V_2} \frac{nrT}{V}dV$.

Integrate this.

After that, from Boyle's law at constant temperature, $PV=constant$
, thus,

$\frac{P_1}{P_2}=\frac{V_2}{V_1}$.

Now you can solve your question. You can get the value of temperature using the ideal gas equation.